# Logback JMSAppender not cleaning up connections with ActiveMQ

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, logback

i am trying to use JMSAppenders in Logback. I tried out a simple app to do that and have successfully sent logs into queues in ActiveMQ.

```
package test;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class LoggerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("test");
        logger.debug("debug");
        logger.info("info");
        logger.warn("warn");
        logger.error("error", new Exception(""));


    }
}
```

Everything runs fine but this application wont terminate even after all the statements in main have executed.

After some poking around I noticed that after the main thread ends  there were two non daemon threads active 
ActiveMQ Transport and DestroyJavaVM
I believe this DestoryJavaVM thread came into being after main thread exited.

I think this has something to do with sessions/connections not closing. If I terminate the broker, the app also exits.

There is a `stop()` method in JMSQueueAppender that closes sessions but it seems its never called, apparently `stop` method is not called for other appenders as well -- i tried it on RollingFileAppender.

I tried the same setup with HornetQ and it works fine but not with activeMQ

I am using slf4j 1.6.4, logback 1.0.0 and activemq 5.5.0

Heres the logback configuration

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are by default assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder -->
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>


<appender name="Queue" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.JMSQueueAppender">
    <InitialContextFactoryName>
        org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
    </InitialContextFactoryName>
    <ProviderURL>tcp://localhost:61616</ProviderURL>
    <QueueConnectionFactoryBindingName>
        ConnectionFactory
    </QueueConnectionFactoryBindingName>
    <QueueBindingName>dynamicQueues/MyQueue</QueueBindingName>
</appender>


<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="Queue" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>

<logger name="org.apache.activemq" additivity="false" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</logger>

</configuration>
```

and pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>LoggerTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>LoggerTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
<!--            <scope>runtime</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
<!--            <scope>runtime</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Can anybody point out whats wrong with this setup. Thanks in advance

Comment: no one to answer?? Same problem here...

Answer (score 1):

The ActiveMQ transport stays alive until it gets shut down explicitly, which LogBack obviously does not automatically.

One can trigger the shut down via:

```
ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
// Check for logback implementation of slf4j
if (loggerFactory instanceof LoggerContext) {
    LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) loggerFactory;
    context.stop();
}
```

Taken from here: [Do I need to flush events when shutting down using logback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3678755/492462)

Verified with ActiveMQ 5.7.0, LogBack 1.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.1.10 onwards, logback takes care of stopping the current logback-classic context (and all the appenders) when the web-app is stopped or reloaded. Try updating your logback version and check once.

Here's the updated doc: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#webShutdownHook